# Reading Analog Input Only Reaches ~ +/-5V, instead of +/- 10V Range

Tags: labview

I have a NI DAQ USB-6341 w/ BNC termination. I have a device that outputs a +/- 10V signal indicating its current status. The device operates correctly, signal confirmed using a multimeter.

The DAQ is also CAPABLE of reading the signal correctly- when attached to an analog input channel, the test panel successfully reads a 10V range.

[image]

However, when I create a simple VI to read the voltage, it absolutely refuses to read anything exceeding 5.473V or below -5.306V.

[image]

Is there some sort of configuration I'm missing here? Some setting to 'unlock' the full range? I have used the analog output to put out a +/- 10V signal before with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

In DAQmx create channel.vi, you can configure voltage range.

Please check short Labview help.

[image]

If you want to set up V range as -10V to 10V,

Please, try this setup.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I can't believe I forgot to change the default values- I'm not even new to LabView either D:

Answer (score 0):

Since nothing is specified in terms of configuration labview will generate a default configuration that is somehow wrong. You can do two things, either specify the correct configuration manually or use express VIs.

I would use an express VI, you can configure and check those similar to a test panel. When satisfied you can convert the express VI to labview code for further programming.

Comment: Yep, that was it- I forgot to change the default value of the VI to see -10 to 10.

Comment: Can happen, glad to hear your problem is solved. Please mark one of the answers as accepted to complete the question.